# The output does not change synchronously on Moore circuit design

Tags: verilog

I'm designing a Moore machine controlling traffic light.

This is a part of my source code.

```
    always @(negedge resetn or posedge clk) begin
        if ( !resetn )   // reset is allowed
            state <= S0;
        else if ( push_button == 2'b01 ) begin 
        case ( state )
            S0 : state <= S1;
            S1 : state <= S2;
            S2 : state <= S1;
            S3 : state <= S3;
            default : state <= state;
        endcase
        end
        
        else if ( push_button == 2'b10 ) begin 
        case ( state )
            S0 : state <= S3;
            S1 : state <= S3;
            S2 : state <= S2;
            S3 : state <= S1;
            default : state <= state;
        endcase
        end
        else
            state <= state;
    end


    always @(posedge clk) begin

        case ( state )
            S0 : led_output = 6'b111111;
            S1 : led_output = 6'b010100;
            S2 : led_output = 6'b100010;
            S3 : led_output = 6'b110110;   
            default : led_output = 6'b000000;
        endcase
    end
    
endmodule
```

I want this code to change their state as input (button) comes in and also change the output value at the same time. But the problem is, while testing it with simulation, the state does change immediately while the output value does not.

For example, let's say initial state was `S0`, and I gave button input `2'b10`. Then the state does change to `S3`, but the output does not change to `6'b110110`.

Can you give me a hint or answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use sequential logic for `led_output`, which means it will change 1 clock cycle after `state`.  You can use combinational logic instead which causes `led_output` to change in the same cycle as `state`:

```
always @* begin
    case ( state )
        S0 : led_output = 6'b111111;
        S1 : led_output = 6'b010100;
        S2 : led_output = 6'b100010;
        S3 : led_output = 6'b110110;   
        default : led_output = 6'b000000;
    endcase
end
```